# Installing Gnome Classic on Ubuntu Server 12.04.1 64bit

Tags: server, gui, gnome-classic

I've installed Ubuntu Server Edition and setup open ssh,samba and lamp on my home desktop just to work on LAN. I also want setup a GUI on it for daily use.

#### I've already performed the following

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback
sudo apt-get install lightdm-gtk-greeter
sudo apt-get install xinit
```

I don't want to install Unity or the Gnome3 Shell on my system. Also I haven't found instructions to installing gnome-classic on a server edition(although it shouldn't make a difference).How do I get it to work?

Comment: note that running a gui on a server is discouraged. there's a reason it comes without one.

Comment: also please be aware that while a lot of people think fallback mode is there to placate previous GNOME 2 users, it isn't. it's deprecated and has been dropped from GNOME 3.8 which means that when you eventually upgrade to something equal to or greater than 13.10 (Saucy), fallback mode won't be available anymore.

Comment: also try `sudo service lightdm restart`. see what the output is. if it says service not found or something, try `sudo apt-get install lightdm`

Comment: I did mention that this server was for light usage on my home network(LAN). I'll try the above the next time I install server edition. Currently using mint on that system. Thanks for the help!

Comment: yeah! you may want to look into MATE. it's a fork of GNOME 2 and _is_ maintained, although it is still in the process of migrating away from deprecated technologies.

Answer (score 0):

Warning : Untested since I already have gnome-3

To install ubuntu classic,

> sudo apt-get install gnome-panel

as instructed in [this link](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/03/gnome-classic-in-ubuntu-12-04-its-like-nothing-ever-changed)

Comment: to install fallback mode, you install gnome-session-fallback. not gnome-panel.

Answer (score 0):

```
  apt-get install gnome-panel gnome-settings-daemon metacity nautilus gnome-terminal
```

and then use this xstartup

```
    nano .vnc/xstartup
```

then add this in xstartup

```
    #!/bin/sh
    export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
    unset SESSION_MANAGER
    unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS

    [ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
    [ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
    xsetroot -solid grey
    vncconfig -iconic &

   gnome-panel &
   gnome-settings-daemon &
   metacity &
   nautilus &
   gnome-terminal &
```